# What is Zwieback toast and where can I find it?

Tags: baking, substitutions, shopping, language

I am baking a black forest cake and it calls for zwieback toast.  I cannot find this anywhere.  Does anyone know what this is or where I can find it?

Comment: Zwieback in a black forest cake? That's a strange recipe...

Comment: You cannot find Gerber zwieback or Nabisco zwieback. I have looked in numerous grocery stores and it is not there anywhere. If someone really know where it can be purchased I would appreciate hearing from them.

Comment: It wasn't requested, but since folks are indicating they are having trouble finding the commercial products, here is a link to [King Arthur's recipe][1] for homemade zweiback.

Basically, it is a twice backed yeast-raised bread, somewhat similar to the Italian biscotti.

A long, log shaped loaf is prepared much like any yeast leavend bread, then the next day it is sliced and baked again to dry it out.  

  [1]: http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/zwieback-recipe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Zwieback toast is a twice-baked sweetened toast fed to teething children. It is also known as teething toast, and can be found in the baby aisle of most grocery stores.

Comment: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Zwieback

It's not only for teething childern. There also is Cocos Zwieback! Fancy!

http://www.doit24.de/viewImageByID.jsp?ArtID=45105822&sizefolder=150&size=400

Comment: I also used Zwieback in Germany when I was baking cheesecakes, in place of graham crackers. While not identical, it was close enough for many applications; the reverse should also hold.

Answer (score 4):

Here is [what it looks like](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FPKX34), if you are out shopping.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: http://www.amazon.de/Brandt-Marken-Zwieback-10er-Pack-Packung/dp/B003R7KX5K/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1358415860&sr=8-1 This is the original!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best receipe for zwieback I have found. The Arthur one is all hodgepodge throw it all together 
http://www.food.com/recipe/zwieback-toast-teething-cookies-156724?scaleto=48.0&st=null&mode=metric